# __new__ is not getting called in object creation

Tags: python, class, oop, object, python-2.x

case 1:

```
class Person:
    def __new__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        print "called"
        return super(Person, cls).__new__(cls, *args, **kwargs)

p=Person()
```

case 2:

```
class Person(object):
    def __new__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        print "called"
        return super(Person, cls).__new__(cls, *args, **kwargs)

p=Person()
```

In first case, the `__new__()` method is not called but in 2nd case it does.

If it doesn't get called, then how is `Person` object being created?

Comment: I'm 99.999% certain that you have this backward, and `__new__` is _not_ called in the first case, but _is_ in the second.

Comment: See [here](https://repl.it/repls/VigorousHummingPreprocessor) for a test.

Comment: Anyway: If you don't already understand old-style classes, the simplest thing to do is just not bother to learn anything about them except how to not accidentally create them. It's archaic knowledge which is very unlikely to ever be useful to you. Of course if you're curious, or if you (or someone else searching this question) happens to run into one of the very rare cases where you need to use old-style classes, it's worth having the answer on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 2):

I guess it is something related to [new and old style classes](https://spyhce.com/blog/understanding-new-and-init) in Python2:

> Old-style classes don't actually have a __new__ method because for them __init__ is the constructor, so basically if we would have:
>
> ```
> class A:
>
>     def __new__(cls):
>         print "A.__new__ is called"  # -> this is never called
>
> A()
> ```
>
> the body of __new__ will never be executed in this case because it is not the purpose for old-style classes.

In Python3, the behavior is the same, doesn't matter if you explicitly inherit from the `object` or not:

```
class Person1:
    def __new__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        print("called")
        return super(Person1, cls).__new__(cls, *args, **kwargs)


class Person2(object):
    def __new__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        print("called")
        return super(Person2, cls).__new__(cls, *args, **kwargs)


p1 = Person1()
p2 = Person2()
```

These should print "called" twice when invoked from 3.x.

Comment: The reason the behavior is the same in Python 3 is that you _always_ inherit from `object`, whether you say so or not (which means there are no old-style classes).

Comment: Anyway, normally I'd recommend a link to the doc, but, AFAIK, the only documentation for this is under the [standard type hierarchy](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#the-standard-type-hierarchy) descriptions of "Class Types" and "Classic Classes", and it's far from clear. There might be something in the (somewhat unfinished/out-of-date) [New-Style Classes](https://www.python.org/doc/newstyle/) docs, though.

Comment: @abarnert Yes, that's correct, only one type of classes in 3.x, that's what I've meant.

Answer (score 1):

I was looking for the documentation, and finally found it here:
https://staging2.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0253/

> The type object has a new slot, tp_new, which can act as a factory for
>   instances of the type. Types are now callable, because the tp_call
>   slot is set in PyType_Type (the metatype); the function looks for the
>   tp_new slot of the type that is being called.

To add onto @devforfu's answer, in the old days, `__new__` didn't exist. It was added with the addition of new-style classes.